# Is there an equation for permutations with different numbers of element available?

Tags: combinatorics, discrete-mathematics, permutations, combinations

For example, if we are to arrange the four letters **A** , **B** , **C** and **D**, by permutation we know that there are 4! = 4 * 3 * 2 * 1 = 24 ways available. But if we have 2 of each letters and are still to arrange them into 4 slots, the equation I've got intuitively is
4 * 4 * 4 * 4 = 256 configurations available as this is the largest possible count. On the other hand if we are to fit them into 6 slots we have 4 * 4 * 4 * 4 * 4 * 3 = 3072 possible configurations as 1 letter has run out. My questions are:

1. Is there a way to generalise permutations with fixed slots, but varying numbers of each element available?
2. Is there a way to convert regular permutations to the specific kind above? For example, for 4 slots and 8 available elements the regular permutation would be 8 * 7 * 6 * 5 , but if we are to take specific letters into account it would be 4 * 4 * 4 * 4.

P.S. the content above might be false; please correct me if that's the case!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you have four copies of each of the four letters, there are indeed
$4\times 4\times 4\times 4$ ways to fill four slots with those letters.

But you only have two copies of each letter. You nevertheless still claim that for each way you can fill the first two slots (which you can do in $4\times 4$ ways), there are $4\times 4$ ways to fill the remaining two slots.
But one of these $4\times 4$ ways to fill the first two slots was to put As in both slots. Now you do not have any more As to fill the remaining slots, so you have only
$3\times 3 = 9$ (not $4\times 4$) ways to finish the arrangement.

If you put two different letters in the first two slots, for example A and then B, you cannot fill the remaining two slots with two As or with two Bs, so you do not have $4\times 4$ ways to fill the remaining slots. All the other arrangements from A, B, C, D with repetition are available, so you have $4\times 4 - 2 = 14$ ways in which you can fill the remaining two slots.

When you have enough copies of letters to have some repetitions but so few copies that you might "run out" of a letter, problems of this kind can get complicated.
In your particular case, you can count the ways by considering that there are $4$ ways to fill the first two slots with the same letter, and $9$ ways to fill the remaining slots in each of those cases; but also $4 \times 3 = 12$ ways to fill the first two slots with two different letters, and $14$ ways to finish each of those arrangements, so the total is

$$ 4 \times 9 + 12 \times 14 = 204. $$

Another way is as follows: the four slots can have all four different letters, or two of one and one each of two others, or two pairs. Count the three cases separately:

For all different letters, $4! = 24$ ways.

For two of one letter and one each of two others, $4$ ways to choose the doubled letter, for each of those there are $\binom42 = 6$ ways to choose which slots this letter goes into, and for each of those we have $3$ letters remaining to fill the leftmost remaining slot, then $2$ letters for the remaining slot, for a total of
$4 \times 6\times 3\times 2 = 144$ ways.

For two each of two letters, we have $\binom42 = 6$ ways to choose which two letters to use, and for each of those choices we have $\binom42 = 6$ ways to choose which two slots are filled by the letter that comes first in alphabetic order; the other slots can only be filled by the other letter in one way, so that's a total of
$6\times 6 = 36$ ways.

Add up the three cases:

$$ 24 + 144 + 36 = 204. $$

Comment: Thank you so much! Is there a way to generalise this process though? The ultimate problem I'm working on is to find out the number of possible configurations of a 2*2*2 Rubik's Cube.

Comment: A Rubik's cube has a lot of additional features, such as the fact that each corner has three colored squares that always stay connected to each other and are always in the same orientation relative to each other, but the corner can be rotated away and come back with the colors permuted. The usual tool for studying Rubik's cubes as far as I'm aware is group theory rather than combinatorics.

Comment: Thank you! What about simply considering combinatorics with different numbers of elements available though? Is there an equation summarising all conditions, or do we have to analyse them case by case?

Comment: Do you assume you can take the cube apart and reassemble it any way you like, or do you start with a solved cube and scramble it by rotating the parts as designed? If you're reassembling you can use combinatorics with possibly just a little group theory (depending on whether you consider rotations of the whole cube to be "different"), but the permutations are the positions of the eight corner cubes and the three choices of orientation for each corner. No special cases required.

Comment: Yup I'm considering the first case. Is there a common process for solving it, like in the form of an equation or something?

Answer (score 2):

Suppose you have 2 As and 2Bs, so you have
$$
A1, A2, B1, B2, C, D
$$
Then there are $6!$ ways to put them in 6 slots.

But since the two $As$ are equivalent, for any one of these permutations, there's another (with $A1$ and $A2$ swapped) that's "the same", and the same argument goes for the two $Bs$. So you've overcounted by a factor of $4$. The correct answer is $6!/4$.

More generally, if you have $k_1$ of item 1, up to $k_n$ of item $n$, the number of indistinguishable permutations is

$$
\frac{(k_1 + k_2 + \ldots + k_n)!}{k_1! k_2! \cdots k_n!}.
$$

Comment: Thanks! Is there a way we could apply this formula to the situation in the question though(with limited slots available)?

Comment: i see from the comments on another answer that this is an XY-problem, so I won't bother answering.