# What is the number of possible configurations of a 2*2*2 Rubik's cube?

Tags: combinatorics, discrete-mathematics, permutations, combinations, rubiks-cube

This is a follow-up question of [Is there an equation for permutations with different numbers of element available?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3868197/is-there-an-equation-for-permutations-with-different-numbers-of-element-availabl/3868261#3868261)

For a regular permutation, the number of possible configurations for a 2 * 2 * 2 cube(not considering symmetries) would be (4*6)!=24! . However, since for every colour only 4 blocks are available the case would be a lot more complex. So my questions are:

1. What is the number of possible configurations of a 2 * 2 * 2 Rubik's cube(without considering symmetry)?
2. Is there a way to generalise this process, so that we could apply the same procedure to similar cases, for example a 3 * 3 * 3 Rubik's cube?
3. What is the number of possible configurations of a 2 * 2 * 2 Rubik's cube if symmetry is to be considered(might be related to group theory...)?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This page https://www.therubikzone.com/number-of-combinations/ has the number of permutations up to a 10x10, although if you wanted even more you can calculate it via the formula found here: https://oeis.org/A075152

This is going to be way less than just rearranging any of the "stickers" on the cube, as most of these are not a valid rubiks cube permutation.